# Pop-up Infoboxes on multiple pushpins on a Bing Map, pins clickable but infobox not showing

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

I'm going round and round in circles with this.  I'm trying to add several pushpins with a single infobox which is displayed next to the clicked pushpin.  I can get the pins to show and be clickable, but the infobox isn't showing.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&mkt=de-de" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=AhrgxvPMzaWNe4oDZqelNzT-SoWigBK7H8cSBqZ2jLXpq4O9IcQ1YktvHhqT7_8F' async defer></script> "

<div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 300px;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function init(){

    // Initialize the map
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"),
        {
            credentials: "My Bing Maps API Key",
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
        }
    );


    var infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), {
        visible: false
    });

    infobox.setMap(map);

    // Create a collection to store multiple pins
    var pins = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();

    // Create pins
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        var position = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(53 + i, -1);

        // Creates a Pushpin
        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(position, {title: 'pin' + i} );
        pin.metadata = {
            title: 'Pin ' + i, 
            description: 'Description for pin ' + i
        };

        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', pushpinClicked);
        // Adds the pin to the collection instead of adding it directly to the Map
        pins.push(pin);
    }

    // Adds all pins at once
    map.entities.push(pins);
}

function pushpinClicked(e) {
        //Make sure the infobox has metadata to display.
        if (e.target.metadata) {
            //Set the infobox options with the metadata of the pushpin.
            infobox.setOptions({
                location: e.target.getLocation(),
                title: e.target.metadata.title,
                description: e.target.metadata.description,
                visible: true
            });
        }
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your referencing Bing Maps V7 in the script tag. That version was deprecated years ago. Its redirecting behind the scenes to v8, but that's not 100% backwards compatible and may be causing issues. Here is the same sample running on V8: https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Infobox_MultiplePushpins

Comment: Hi @rbrundritt, thanks for your reply.  I tried that code sample but when I tried to make it map specific locations rather than the randomly generated one, I couldn't get the pushpins to show.  Do you know an example where you can feed in known locations to the pushpins which are then clickable?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Try zooming the map out, maybe the coordinates aren't were you think they are. Make sure you didn't leave out the 'new' keyword when creating pushpins/location objects, that is an easy mistake to make that's hard to debug. Make sure it looks something like this: `new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(53, -1))`

Comment: Thank you, that's sorted it!